# How do i achieve GETBIT functionality in BIGQUERY

Tags: google-bigquery

We currently check GETBIT(FIELD,9)=1 in teradata, so that the bit value matches =1 , then some logic.

Since, we move to BQ now, how do i get the same logic to work in BQ? I see only BIT_COUNT under Bit functions, not sure how it would work in my case. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution - BigQuery Standard SQL

```
select (field>> 9) & 1
```

You can create UDF and then use it as in below sketch

```
create temp function getbit(target_arg int64, target_bit_arg int64) as (
  (target_arg >> target_bit_arg) & 1
);
select getbit(field, pos) 
from ...
```